じゃありません or ありません
EJUを受けるつもりはありません。私が受ける大学の入学試験に必要ありませんから。
Why 必要じゃありません is not used here.
Please help me here.

It could be either in this case. As it is currently written, 必要ありません is simply omitting が →　必要（が）ありません.
The exact meaning would only differ slightly, but the overall meaning is the same.


～必要（が）ありません　→　[There is]{LLLLLLLL} no need to/for ～
vs

～必要じゃありません　→　[It is]{LLLLL} not necessary that ～



